# Retrieve all sends to a specific records in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, automationstudio

How the query shall look like if we want to retrieve all emails a specific contact received?

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted so others can easily identify that this question hast been answered correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that Marketing Cloud stores this information in Data Views for a limited time only. Therefore you should create an automation that copies the new data to a separate data extension first and query this data extension then.

However, to query the Sent Data View for a specific Subscriber, the query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    JobID,
    EventDate,
    TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
FROM
    _Sent
WHERE
   SubscriberKey = 'YOUR_SUBSCRIBER_ID'
```

To get more information regarding the send, you can join the Job Data View in like this:

```sql
SELECT
    s.JobID,
    s.EventDate,
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    j.FromName,
    j.ShedTime,
    j.EmailName,
    j.EmailSubject
FROM
    _Sent s
JOIN
    _Job j
ON
    s.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = j.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID
WHERE
   SubscriberKey = 'YOUR_SUBSCRIBER_ID'
```

**Further information:**

- [Data View: Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5)
- [Data View: Job](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5)

Comment: This is a valid question and we should be welcoming of members with all levels of experience in this community - please try not to downvote questions of this type.

Comment: @MatthewWash That is definitely true, therefore I answered the question and didn‘t downvote it ;) Your comment would therefore be better placed at the question rather than my answer.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to comment at the top, not after your answer, my bad